# Batch Apex and cursors

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I'm having difficulty with this paragraph from the Apex batch documentation. it's about query cursors which I haven't learned about. Can someone please explain QC's and what's going on here?

A user can have up to 50 query cursors open at a time. For example, if 50 cursors are open and a client application still logged in as the same user attempts to open a new one, the oldest of the 50 cursors is released. Note that this limit is different for the batch Apexstart method, which can have up to five query cursors open at a time per user. The other batch Apex methods have the higher limit of 50 cursors.

Cursor limits for different Force.com features are tracked separately. For example, you can have 50Apex query cursors, 50 batch cursors, and 50Visualforce cursors open at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand Query Cursors to return a batched and [locked](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database_batch.htm#database_querylocator) list of records (locked, in the sense that other updates/edits, outside of batch Apex for example, are prevented as long as the records being worked with). Typically Query Cursors, in Apex, are returned by the [`Database.getQueryLocator`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_methods_system_database.htm) method.

The records are not all returned at once, but are broken up into batches of data. If there were 500 records, perhaps only the first 200 would be returned (this is determined by the [batch scope/size](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database.htm#executeBatch), which is defaulted to 200), then the batch execute code will run again for the second 200, and again for the last 100 records. The same concept applies to [Visualforce pagination](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/07/14/visualforce-page-with-pagination/) (note the call to [`Database.getQueryLocator`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_methods_system_database.htm) used in the standard Controller initialization in the example).

Regarding the limits, basically, you can only have 50 calls to [`Database.getQueryLocator`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_methods_system_database.htm), 50 batch Apex classes, and 50 Visualforce pages with pagination (using the method described in the example) open/running at the same time (this limit used to be 5; 50 is a huge improvement).

Comment: Thanks Matt. So is a query cursor the same as a query locator? Also, mind if I ask you a follow up?  In my batch class, I have a start, execute, and finish method that I implement. The start class returns Database.getQueryLocator('select id, f1, from contact where f1 :DirtySet');  . Ok, when I call this in the execute, are those records locked? I'm concerned about race conditions and deadlocks, but this seems take care of that problem. Is that right?

Comment: I'm fairly sure Query Cursor and Query Locater are both the same. If you're running your batch on a daily schedule, and the batch doesn't take longer than 24 hours to execute, you shouldn't run into any problems with locked records. I haven't had an issue with locked records in a batch before, though. The information I have on how records are locked comes from the [QueryLocator documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_methods_system_database_batch.htm).

Comment: So what are some causes for batch failures? how do you manage them usually?

Comment: That's a really open-ended question; it depends on the batch. To manage failures, I usually log them to a Batch Status object (created specifically for monitoring batch failures), and I have an e-mail sent when the batch completes (finish).